# $|f(z)|=c\in\Bbb R\forall z\in\Omega$ for $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$ open and connected $\implies f$ is constant. Why must $\Omega$ be open, connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$, and $\Omega$ is open and connected. If $|f(z)|$ is constant it is known that $f$ is constant on $\Omega$

The proof of this fact says that if $f$ is not constant then $f(\Omega)$ is open as the image of an open by a holomorphic function. But a circle of radius $c\in\Bbb R_+$ is not open and $f(\Omega)$ wouldn't be open either as a subset of that circle, which contradicts the first sentence.

**Question 1**

Where is the connectedness of $\Omega$ used in the above proof?

**Question 2**

Why should $\Omega$ have any of the two constraints? Is the following proof invalid?

> writing $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ since $f$ is holomorphic the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}~~\text{ and }~~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$ $\forall (x+iy)\in\Omega\ ~|f(x+iy)|=\sqrt{u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)}=c\in\Bbb R_+$
>
> $\implies\frac{\partial }{\partial x}[\sqrt{u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)}]=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}[\sqrt{u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)}]=0$
>
> $\iff (u_x+v_x)(u^2+v^2)^{-{1\over2}}=(u_y+v_y)(u^2+v^2)^{-{1\over2}}=0$
>
> If $u^2+v^2=|f|^2=0\forall z\in\Omega$ then $f=0$ and we're done
>
> Let's suppose $u^2+v^2\ne0$ then we can divide by $(u^2+v^2)^{-{1\over2}}$ it on both sides to get: $$u_x+v_x=u_y+v_y=0$$ by the C-R equations $$u_x-u_y=u_y+u_x\implies u_y=-v_x=0$$ substituting $v_x=0$ into $u_x+v_x=0$ $$u_x=0\implies v_y=0$$
>
> All the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are zero and since $f'(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)=0$ we get that $f$ is constant.

Comment: In your proof, you use the fact of connectedness of domain: If a multivariable function has its total derivative zero in a connected domain, then the function is constant on that domain

Comment: Let $f=1$ on $B(0,1)$ and $f=-1$ on $B(2,1)$ then $|f|$ is constant but $f$ is not. You need connectedness so the constant is the same.

Comment: The conditions are sufficient, not necessary. $f$ may be constant without $\Omega$ being either open or connected.

Comment: But the connectedness is necessary, no?

Comment: Your proof doesn't deal with the case where $f$ can be zero but not identically zero.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking in regards to connectedness.

Comment: What do you mean zero without being identically zero? $f=0\iff |f|=0$

Comment: In your example with the two discs centered in 0 and 2 the domain is not connected. And if you meant closed circles then $f$ is not continuous so not holomorphic. So I don't see how the connectedness property of $\Omega$ is not necessary

Comment: You have lost me here. Your proof deals with the case where $f(z) =0$ for all $z \in \Omega$ or $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \Omega$. This does not cover all cases.

Comment: You were asking in Question 1 where connectedness is used, I am giving an example where $\Omega$ is not connected, but is open and $|f|$ is constant but $f$ is not. This should indicate where connectedness is used.